# How to update a table while joining based on a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_TWO_DAY_EXTEND 
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE CHECKOUT
    SET CHECK_IN_DATE = CHECK_IN_DATE + 2 
    JOIN PATRON ON PATRON.PAT_ID = CHECKOUT.PAT_ID
    FROM CHECKOUT  
    WHERE PATRON.PAT_TYPE = 'STUDENT';
END;

EXEC PRC_TWO_DAY_EXTEND;
```

Basically I need to just add two days to the check in date but I cant figure out how to join them and then update them, because its based on whether or not `PAT_TYPE = 'STUDENT'`

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 1):

Your date arithmetics suggests Oracle, so let me assume that's the database you are running.

In that database, you could phrase the query as:

```
update checkout c
set check_in_date = check_in_date + 2
where exists (
    select 1
    from patron p
    where p.pat_id = c.pat_id and p.pat_type = 'STUDENT'
)
```

This updates the check-in date of rows whose `pat_id` can be found in `patron` with a `pat_type` having value `'STUDENT'`.

Comment: Thank you, I do not have enough reputation to up vote this but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to use the `MERGE` as follows:

```
Merge into checkout c
Using
(select pat_id 
   From patron
  Where pat_type = 'STUDENT') p
On (p.pat_id = c.pat_id)
When matched then
Update set c.check_in_date = c.check_in_date + 2
```